# Using Gmail API's quickstart to allow multiple OAuth logins

Tags: c#, oauth, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to use Google's quickstart sample for Gmail API with Google OAuth but  the program only allows for a one time log in screen. How can I remove it so I can login every time the app opens? 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#notes
I have downloaded the code and it runs - but again I can only login once

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GmailQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Gmail API service.
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");

            // List labels.
            IList<Label> labels = request.Execute().Labels;
            Console.WriteLine("Labels:");
            if (labels != null && labels.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var labelItem in labels)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", labelItem.Name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No labels found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `token.json` file every time your script ends, so it will need to generate them (and login) every time. The best place would be at the end of your class `Program`:

```
namespace GmailQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        ...
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No labels found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
        File.Delete("token.json"); //New line
    }
}
```

You can read more about Gmail API and authentication [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/#auth_and_the_gmail_api).

Comment: token.json isnt a file its a folder the client library FileDataStore takes a folder name not a file name.

Answer (score 0):

The google .net client library by default stores your credentials in the directory you denoted by credPath In this case token.json folder.  Each user is denoted by the  "user", line in your code.  If you change "user" to something random then it will prompt you to login every time.

This way you can change between users.  Just make sure to delete the credentials stored in token.json folder or create or own implementation of iDatstore that does not store these credentials.